# How to changing the colour of data within scatter plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set and I would like to change the colour of my scatter plot. I have 5 reps, each contains 5 data points (r1dp1.20, r1dp2.20, r1dp3.20,r1dp4.20,r5dp5.20). I would like to change the code so that rep is one colour e.g. all the data in r1 would be red all the data in r2 green etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    ggplot(data=sdf1,(aes(x=real.time, y=r1dp1.20,r1dp2.20,r1dp3.20,r1dp4.20,+
                            r1dp5.20,r4dp1.20,r4dp2.20,r4dp3.20,r4dp4.20,r4dp5.20,+
                            r2dp1.20,r2dp2.20,r2dp3.20,r2dp4.20,r2dp5.20,r3dp1.20,+
                          r3dp2.20,r3dp3.20,r3dp4.20,r3dp5.20,r5dp1.20,r5dp2.20,r5dp3.20,r5dp4.20,r5dp5.20))) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method=lm , color="red", se=FALSE)+
      xlab('Time')+
      ylab('O2 concetration mg/l')
```

Comment: Looks like you have a non-tidy data frame. Don't see the data, but it appears you need to use something like `tidyr::pivot_longer`. After that, you can add to the `aes` `color = xx` where xx is your y category name.

Comment: Agree with @markhogue - [see here for information on "tidy data" and how to use it](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  If you want additional help here, please provide a sample of your data frame via pasting the out put of `dput(sdf1)` into your question (assuming the dataset is not too large).  You can also post a sample of that data within `dput()` if it's too large to share.